# Open offline jpg-images in a command-line-application in Objective-C under Mac OS X 10.6.8 and Xcode 3.2.6

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-snow-leopard, xcode3.2, xcode3

What I do: I'm pretty new to Objective-C and I write an command-line-application on my old Macbook 2,1 that works with pictures.

My problem: I just want to get the width and height as a number (int, NSInteger, NSNumber, …) of a picture saved on my local hard-drive „Macintosh HD“.

Relevance for others: There must be a programatical way, to work with pictures. This is pretty basic.

My work platform: I'm developing on Mac OS X 10.6.8 with Xcode 3.2.6.

My research history: I already looked for cook-book-recipies and background-knowledge at stackoverflow and a few other sites to make my following trials, but I wasn't successful, yet. I present all I tried in the following. In advance, nothing worked.

//BildOeffner.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface BildOeffner : NSView 
    -(BildOeffner*) init;
    - (NSNumber*) extrahiereBildBreite:(NSString*) bildPfad;
@end
```

//BildOeffner.m:

```
#import "BildOeffner.h"
@implementation BildOeffner
    // extracts the image width
    - (NSNumber*) extrahiereBildBreite:(NSString*) bildPfad{
    NSBitmapImageRep* nsImageRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithContentsOfFile:bildPfad];
    NSInteger extrahierteBildBreite =[nsImageRep pixelsWide];
    NSNumber* bildBreite = [NSNumber numberWithInt:extrahierteBildBreite];
    return bildBreite;
    }
@end
```

The code shows no compile-errors in the editor, but there are errors in the build-results: The Error-Message:

```
Ld build/Debug/FotobuchErsteller_0 normal x86_64
cd /Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk     -L/Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/build/Debug     -F/Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/build/Debug -filelist /Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/build/FotobuchErsteller_0.build/Debug/FotobuchErsteller_0.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FotobuchErsteller_0.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -framework Foundation -o /Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/build/Debug/FotobuchErsteller_0

Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSImage", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref-to-NSImage in BildOeffner.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSView", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BildOeffner in BildOeffner.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSView", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_BildOeffner in BildOeffner.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSBitmapImageRep", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref-to-NSBitmapImageRep in BildOeffner.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

then I tried the following:

//BildAnalyst.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface BildAnalyst : NSObject
@property (assign) NSArray* bilderListe;
@property (assign) NSArray* bildObjektListe;
@property (assign) NSNumber* erwarteteBildHoehe;
@property (assign) NSNumber* erwarteteBildBreite;

-(BildAnalyst*) init;
-(BildAnalyst*) initWith:(NSArray*) neueBilderListe;

- (NSArray *)bilderListe;
- (void)setBilderListe:(NSArray *) neueBilderListe;
- (NSArray *)bildObjektListe;
- (void)setBildObjektListe:(NSArray *) neueBildObjektListe;
- (NSNumber*)erwarteteBildHoehe;
- (void)setErwarteteBildHoehe:(NSNumber*) neueErwarteteBildHoehe;
- (NSNumber*)erwarteteBildBreite;
- (void)setErwarteteBildBreite:(NSNumber*) neueErwarteteBildBreite;

- (void) erstelleListeAllerBilderImOrdner:(NSString*) absoluterPfadZumOrdner;
- (void) analysiereBilderListe;
@end
```

//BildAnalyst.m:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BildAnalyst.h"
#import "Bild.h"
@implementation BildAnalyst

- (id)init {
self = [super init];
    if (self){
    self.bilderListe = nil;
    self.erwarteteBildHoehe = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3024];
    self.erwarteteBildBreite = [NSNumber numberWithInt:4032];
    }
return self;
}

/*Der explizite Konstruktor dieser Klasse.
 Parameter: NSMutableArray neueBilderListe
 Rueckgabe: BildAnalyst bildAnalyst*/
-(BildAnalyst*) initWith:(NSMutableArray*) neueBilderListe{
self = [super init];
    if (self){
        self.bilderListe = neueBilderListe;
    }
return self;
}

- (void) setBilderListe:(NSArray *) neueBilderListe{
    self.bilderListe = neueBilderListe;
}

- (NSArray *) bilderListe{
    return self.bilderListe;
}

- (void)setBildObjektListe:(NSArray *) neueBildObjektListe{
    self.bildObjektListe = neueBildObjektListe;
}

- (NSArray *)bildObjektListe{
    return self.bildObjektListe;
}

- (NSNumber*)erwarteteBildHoehe{
    return self.erwarteteBildHoehe;
}

- (void)setErwarteteBildHoehe:(NSNumber*) neueErwarteteBildHoehe{
    self.erwarteteBildHoehe = neueErwarteteBildHoehe;
}

- (NSNumber*)erwarteteBildBreite{
    return self.erwarteteBildBreite;
}

- (void)setErwarteteBildBreite:(NSNumber*) neueErwarteteBildBreite{
    self.erwarteteBildBreite = neueErwarteteBildBreite;
}


/* Die folgende Methode dient dem Auslesen eines Ordners und dem Speichern von darin enthaltenen Objekten in erster Hierarchieebene in ein Array, welches die Instanzvariable "bilderListe" befuellt.
 Parameter NSString* absoluterPfadZumOrdner*/
- (void) erstelleListeAllerBilderImOrdner:(NSString*) absoluterPfadZumOrdner{
    NSError* fehlerBeimLesenDesBilderordners;
    NSFileManager* nsFileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [nsFileManager changeCurrentDirectoryPath:absoluterPfadZumOrdner];
    NSArray* dateiListe = [nsFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:absoluterPfadZumOrdner error:&fehlerBeimLesenDesBilderordners];
    [self setBilderListe:dateiListe];
}

/*Die folgende Methode dient der Analyse der Bilder, welche in einem Ordner gefunden wurden. Sie bestimmt das Bildformat und speichert die Bilder als Objekte in die Instanzvariable "bildObjektListe".
Parameter NSArray bilderListe*/
- (void) analysiereBilderListe {
    NSUInteger i, count = [[self bilderListe] count];
    NSMutableArray* neueBildObjektListe = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        NSString* bildPfad = [[self bilderListe] objectAtIndex:i];
        NSBitmapImageRep* nsImageRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithContentsOfFile:bildPfad];
        NSInteger extrahierteBildHoehe = [nsImageRep pixelsHigh];
        NSNumber* bildHoehe = [NSNumber numberWithInt:extrahierteBildHoehe];
        NSInteger extrahierteBildBreite =[nsImageRep pixelsWide];
        NSNumber* bildBreite = [NSNumber numberWithInt:extrahierteBildBreite];
        Bild* bild = [[Bild alloc] init];
        [bild setVollstaendigerBildName:bildPfad];
        if ((bildHoehe == self.erwarteteBildHoehe) && (bildBreite == self.erwarteteBildBreite)) {
            [bild setBildformat:hochformat];
        } else if ((bildHoehe == self.erwarteteBildBreite) && (bildBreite == self.erwarteteBildHoehe)) {
            [bild setBildformat:querformat];
        } else if (bildHoehe ==bildBreite){
            [bild setBildformat:quadratisch];
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    [neueBildObjektListe insertObject:bild atIndex:i];
    }
    self.bildObjektListe = neueBildObjektListe;
}
@end
```

with the class „Bild“:

//Bild.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef enum {hochformat, quadratisch, querformat} Bildformat;

@interface Bild : NSObject 
@property (assign) NSString *vollstaendigerBildName;
@property (assign) Bildformat bildformat;

- (Bild*)init;
- (Bild*)init:(NSString *) bildName nunDasBildformat:(Bildformat)dasBildFormat;
- (void)setVollstaendigerBildName:(NSString *) neuerVollstaendigerBildName;
- (NSString *)vollstaendigerBildName;
- (void)setBildformat:(Bildformat) neuesBildformat;
- (Bildformat)bildformat;
@end
```

//Bild.m:

```
#import "Bild.h"

@implementation Bild

- (Bild*)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        self.vollstaendigerBildName = @"";
        self.bildformat = hochformat;
    }
    return self;
}

/*Der explizite Konstruktor dieser Klasse.
 Parameter NSString bildName
 Parameter Bildformat dasBildFormat
 Rueckgabe Bild bild*/
- (Bild*)init:(NSString *)bildName nunDasBildformat:(Bildformat)dasBildFormat {
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        self.vollstaendigerBildName = bildName;
        self.bildformat = dasBildFormat;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setVollstaendigerBildName:(NSString *) neuerVollstaendigerBildName{
    self.vollstaendigerBildName = neuerVollstaendigerBildName;
}

- (NSString *) vollstaendigerBildName{
    return self.vollstaendigerBildName;
}

- (void)setBildformat:(Bildformat) neuesBildformat{
    self.bildformat = neuesBildformat;
}

- (Bildformat)bildformat{
    return self.bildformat;
}
@end
```

The code shows no compile-errors in the editor, but there are errors in the build-results: The error-Message:

```
Ld build/Debug/FotobuchErsteller_0 normal x86_64
cd /Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 
-isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk         -L/Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/build/Debug     
-F/Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/build/Debug 
-filelist /Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/build/FotobuchErsteller_0.build/Debug/FotobuchErsteller_0.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FotobuchErsteller_0.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 
-framework Foundation -o /Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/build/Debug/FotobuchErsteller_0

Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSBitmapImageRep", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSBitmapImageRep in BildAnalyst.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

then I tried the following with the same class „BildAnalyst“:

I used

```
NSURL* nsUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:bildPfad];
CIImage* nsImageRep = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:nsUrl];
```

instead of

```
NSBitmapImageRep* nsImageRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithContentsOfFile:bildPfad];
```

The code shows no compile-errors in the editor, but there are errors in the build-results: the error-Message:

```
Ld build/Debug/FotobuchErsteller_0 normal x86_64
cd /Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk     -L/Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/build/Debug     -F/Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/build/Debug -filelist /Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/build/FotobuchErsteller_0.build/Debug/FotobuchErsteller_0.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FotobuchErsteller_0.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -framework Foundation -o /Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/build/Debug/FotobuchErsteller_0

Undefined symbols:

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CIImage", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref-to-CIImage in BildAnalyst.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

then I tried the following with the same class „BildAnalyst“:

I used

```
NSURL* nsUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:bildPfad];
NSData* nsData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:nsUrl];
UIImage* nsImageRep = [UIImage imageWithData:nsData];
```

instead of

```
NSBitmapImageRep* nsImageRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithContentsOfFile:bildPfad];
```

The code shows compile-errors at the line with UIImage. The error-Messages:

```
CompileC build/FotobuchErsteller_0.build/Debug/FotobuchErsteller_0.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BildAnalyst.o BildAnalyst.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_2
cd /Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
```

/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=gnu99 
    -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -mfix-and-continue -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2
-iquote /Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/build/FotobuchErsteller_0.build/Debug/FotobuchErsteller_0.build/FotobuchErsteller_0-generated-files.hmap
    -I/Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/build/FotobuchErsteller_0.build/Debug/FotobuchErsteller_0.build/FotobuchErsteller_0-own-target-headers.hmap
    -I/Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/build/FotobuchErsteller_0.build/Debug/FotobuchErsteller_0.build/FotobuchErsteller_0-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/build/FotobuchErsteller_0.build/Debug/FotobuchErsteller_0.build/FotobuchErsteller_0-project-headers.hmap
    -F/Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/build/Debug
    -I/Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/build/Debug/include
    -I/Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/build/FotobuchErsteller_0.build/Debug/FotobuchErsteller_0.build/DerivedSources/x86_64
    -I/Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/build/FotobuchErsteller_0.build/Debug/FotobuchErsteller_0.build/DerivedSources -include /var/folders/1J/1J8zfhnuH3Gk3T++j4sPBE+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/FotobuchErsteller_0_Prefix-gqjmlqmlzpuhpyfvtxjjyzqdlikg/FotobuchErsteller_0_Prefix.pch 
    -c /Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/BildAnalyst.m 
    -o /Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/build/FotobuchErsteller_0.build/Debug/FotobuchErsteller_0.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BildAnalyst.o
     /Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/BildAnalyst.m: In function '-[BildAnalyst analysiereBilderListe]':
    /Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/BildAnalyst.m:112: error: 'UIImage' undeclared (first use in this function)
    /Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/BildAnalyst.m:112: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
    /Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/BildAnalyst.m:112: error: for each function it appears in.)
    /Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/BildAnalyst.m:112: error: 'nsImageRep' undeclared (first use in this function)
    /Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/BildAnalyst.m:113: warning: unused variable 'bildHoehe'
    /Users/Edo/Documents/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchSkriptErsteller/FotobuchErsteller_0/BildAnalyst.m:104: warning: 
    unused variable 'neueBildObjektListe'
    {standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_SUP_REFS_$_0
    {standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_0
    {standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_1
    {standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_1
    {standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_2
    {standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_3
    {standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_4
    {standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_5
    {standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_6
    {standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_7
    {standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_8
    {standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_9
    {standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_2
    {standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_10
    {standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_11
    {standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_12

Has anybody a suggestion, what I can improve or perhaps another way? I just want to get the width and height of a picture saved on my local hard-drive „Macintosh HD“ as a number (int, NSInteger, NSNumber, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command-line tools, by default, link only against Foundation. You need to make sure your project is linked against the AppKit framework (or Cocoa, which automatically links to both Foundation or AppKit). Select your project in Xcode, select your target, and click on the "Build Phases" tab. In "Link Binary With Libraries", add AppKit. You should have access to AppKit classes such as `NSImage`.

Comment: Many Thanks! The dependencies are available now! In case that someone searches the precise way, how to add AppKit, here's what I found out: Click under "Overview" in "Target" --> <ApplicationName> --> "Link Binary With Libraries", then "Action" --> "add" --> "Existing Frameworks" --> "AppKit.framework" under the condition, that "All" is marked in the restrictions --> "Add".

Comment: Perhaps, you could add, how to find out, that NSImage is part of AppKit. It's just because I'm looking now for a similar way to import "<SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>" for writing UnitTests and I don't know how to associate it with a particular framework.

Comment: The documentation for each class says at the top what framework it's from. If you look at the docs for `NSImage`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage and scroll to the top, you can see it in the header.